# Invisible router.* variables

Tags: symfony, yaml

In my Sf2 parameters.yml file I've got something like this:

```
router.request_context.base_url: "asddassda"
website_url: "123%router.request_context.base_url%"
```

But when I print website_url somewhere, it only shows "123". Other variables like `router.request_context.host` and `router.request_context.scheme` are NOT visible as well. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you write more about how you use it? Where do you put this parameters and how you retrieve it?

Comment: Well... I use it like this: twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        website_url: "%website_url%"

and then just echo it in the template

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

Somehow parameters that name starts as `router.` are not visable in `config.yml`. Maybe it's a bug. If I get it by `ParametersBag` it works fine.

As a workaround I chenge name to `routerX.` and it works:

```
# app/config/parameters.ini
parameters:
    routerX.request_context.base_url: "asddassda"
    website_url: "123%routerX.request_context.base_url%"
```

And

```
# app/config/config.yml
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

    globals:
        website_url: "%website_url%"
```

And then in `twig` template

```
{{ website_url }}
```

Comment: Ok, but I need this for CommandLine router context, well I could set this manually each time, but I'm wondering why this is happening and if there's a way to make this done properly?

Answer (score 0):

Tried. It's working for me.

Are you sure you didn't overwrite this parameter `router.request_context.base_url` somewhere else in your configuration ?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, none of the router.* variables are visible to me. I got confused because localhost and http are sf2 defaults.

Comment: ...and I made a full search on all files and only framework pop ups results for given keywords